# Flot bar graph selection with highlight/un-highlight

Tags: jquery, flot, highlight, interaction

This code allows you to select multiple bars by highlighting them.
How can I deselect a highlighted (unhighlight) bar while leaving others highlighted?

```
$(function() {

    var sin = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 1) {
        sin.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    }

    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [
        { data: sin, label: "sin(x)"}
    ], {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true
            },
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },
    });

    $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
            plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the complete code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PVL11/8o8h1rc5/31/)

Answer (score 0):

Since Flot does not expose the array of highlighted bars, the simplest solution would be to create such an array yourself and check in the plotclick function if the current bar is already highlighted and in that case, unhighlight it.

Updated code (full code in this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8o8h1rc5/32/)):

```
    var highlights = {};

    $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);

            var indices = item.seriesIndex + '_' + item.dataIndex;
            if (highlights[indices]) {
                plot.unhighlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
                highlights[indices] = false;
            } else {
                plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
                highlights[indices] = true;
            }
        }
    });
```